# Is there a way to calculate the distance between two points without using Pythagorean theorem?

Tags: geometry

In high school I was always taught to use Pythagorean theorem to calculate distance or the distance formulas were always some variation of it. I've never seen a distance formula not using it. I can also see why it's useful because I think that if you have two points $(x_1,…,x_n)$ and $(y_1,…,y_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, you can use Pythagorean theorem $n−1$ times to show that the distance between them is $$\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - y_i)^2}$$ So another question would be if there are other distance formulas why aren't they used?

Comment: Two formulas that do the same thing are really both the same formula. Do you mean a distance formula with a different use?

Comment: Why do you think there is?  Other than replacing values with trig values which do the exact same thing this is the standard/only way to measure the physical distance between to points in euclidean space.  *BUT* in math, distance is only an abstract concept and straight line euclidean distance isn't the only way to think of "distance" and indeed the idea of distance need not have any physical interpretation at all.  Ross Millikan's answer discusses "distance" as mathematicians view it.

Comment: There exist many formulas in geometry involving distances which don't use Cartesian coordinates, for example the [parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law). But then it's not at all clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other distance formulas.  The more technical term is a [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)).  One alternative is the [Manhattan metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry), also called the taxicab metric.  For it we have $d(x,y)=\sum_i |x_i-y_i|$ with the motivation that if you are traveling in a city laid out in blocks the distance from one point to another is the number of blocks north/south plus the number of blocks east/west.  Another is the discrete metric, where the distance between any two different points is $1$.